# How can I see os_trace messages in the debugger?

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb, activity-tracing

I'm trying to add iOS 8's new [activity tracing](http://www.objc.io/issue-19/activity-tracing.html) feature to my app, but I'm not able to see any messages coming from my tracing. I'm using Xcode 6.2 beta 4 to drive my app on an iPod touch running iOS 8.2 beta 4.

```
os_activity_initiate("activity", OS_ACTIVITY_FLAG_DEFAULT, ^{
  os_trace_debug("test tracing");
  doAThing(); // breakpoint on this line
});
```

When I hit the breakpoint, I try

```
(lldb) thread info
thread #11: tid = 0x3b41, ...
```

like the article describes, but I don't see any messages about the activity.

Comment: Does `thread list` show an activity for your thread?  In the article you link to, it shows `activity = 'crash button pressed', 1 messages` in the thread status display.  If in doubt, `thread info -j` will show everything lldb was able to retrieve about that thread.  If the communication with `diagnosticd` (which provides all of the activity/trace message information) timed out, the `activity_query_timed_out` field will be present in the output of `th i -j`.

Comment: No, all I get is the `thread #x: tid = ...` line. There's no activity info or `activity_query_timed_out` when I use the `-j` parameter.

Comment: Try running your program on a Simulator target and use the `ostraceutil` command line program mentioned in the article you linked to once you hit the breakpoint -- that should help to disambiguate whether this is a bug in your program or a bug in lldb.

Comment: I have noticed, that activity tracing does not work for me on a Simulator, try to run on the device

Comment: It appears that only some devices support activity tracing. I get the messages correctly on an iPhone 5, iPhone 6, and iPad mini 3. I do not see any activity or trace messages on the iPod Touch or an iPad mini (1). Requires A6 or newer processor? This is with Xcode 6.2 beta 5.

Comment: It also appears that information only appears if I change the trace calls from `os_trace_debug` to `os_trace`. Still investigating.

Comment: @Greg any luck with this? I'm running on a iPhone 5s and I get any anything from `thread info`. BTW I'm using `os_trace`.